# File uploading - I need to find the absolute (full) path of the tmp_name in PHP

Tags: php, cakephp

While upload a file i will get the `tmp_name` in the array,
I need to find the absolute (full) path of the `tmp_name` that means in which path the file is there( like `var/www/sample/tmp/phpekIgfr`)

```
Array
(
    [name] => profile.jpg
    [type] => image/jpeg
    [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpekIgfr
    [error] => 0
    [size] => 44288
)
```

Comment: you dont need access to that folder. move_uploaded_file($_FILES['tmp_name'],'./uploads/'.$_FILES['name']);

Comment: yes currently i moving the file and find the path.. with out move the uploaded file is there is any way to get the current path of that image ??

Comment: `/tmp/phpekIgfr` ***is*** the full path.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`tmp_name` will always contain the full path.

`/tmp/phpeklgfr`  points to the uploaded file in the  root `/tmp` directory. It does not reside in `/var/www/sample/tmp`.

You can change the location PHP stores temporary files in using the `upload_tmp_dir` php.ini setting.

Comment: Is this an undocumented thing that might go away in future versions without warning? do you have a reference?